# A method in the Dirac 3 LE library always returns 0

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, audio-processing

I'm trying to use the DIRAC 3 LE library to stretch Audio in an Xcode Project and everything works like a charm except for this method:

```
- (NSTimeInterval) currentTime;
```

in DiracAudioPlayerBase.h. This method is supposed to return the current position in the audio-file (according to the Documentation).
But for me this one always returns 0, no matter how long the audio-file was playing. This is also the case when I look at the Demos that are included. Did anyone have the same problem? I hope anyone can help me.

I downloaded the sourcecode from https://github.com/gerasim13/Dirac-3-LE

When I run my App in the Iphone simulator I also get the error message

```
!!! DIRAC ERROR: DiracSetProcessingBeganCallback not supported in this version
```

I don't know if this is at all related. Everything else works fine. I can stretch the sound-file and play it, I just cant get the current position in the audio-file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known limitation of the LE version.

You simply need to purchase the PRO version of Dirac in order for this to work...